# How to add mutiple value to array with inline onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Say I have a html form below, that after I filled out the "pool, ip, port field, then click "Add" button, it will be displayed in the wide textarea, and ip:port pair added to  field array pool.

If I continue to fill in different ip, port pair and click "Add" it will be added to array pool.

If I select a ip:port pair in textarea and click delete, it will be removed from array pool.

I searched this site and  this seems to be achievable through html onclick event with some sort of jquery or javascript function, but I am very new to web like html, jquery, javascript, so I am hoping someone can share some guidance here so I can get started on the right track. example html form below (I am not even sure the html form is exactly the way it should be :)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" id="ipport">
  pool: <input type="text" name="pool">
  IP: <input type="text" name="ip">
  Port: <input type="text" name="port">
  <button onclick="addIPPort()">Add</button>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" >
  IP1:Port1
  IP2:Port2
  </textarea>
  <button onclick="delIPPort()">Delete</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jquery.com/ would be good place to start.

Comment: maybe a `select` element with multiple option would fit better, check the demo http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Since you are a newbie, you should read up on HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Hopefully, that's not too much. I started from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest code even written but it should give you a pretty good start http://jsfiddle.net/7HfGm/1/ I only gave you the add because I discourage blindly using code but it won't be a hard leap from what I provided.

First, you don't need a form if your using javascript.

```
pool: <input type="text" name="pool">
IP:<input type="text" id="ip">
Port: <input type="text" id="port">
<button onclick="addIPPort()">Add</button>
<br>
<select id="select" multiple="multiple"></select>
<button onclick="delIPPort()">Delete</button>
```

I have included links to the jQuery functions used in the code.